# bootstrap dropdown menu on the right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm attempting to change the top navigation bootstrap menu's left-to-right orientation of every item, as well as text alignment to the right; can you tell me how to generate the CSS code for it? i.e

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Home</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
            <li><a href="index-2.html">Option 1: Default</a></li>
            <li><a href="home_services.html">Option 2: Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="home_full.html">Option 3: Full Intro</a></li>
```

Why does class dropdown-menu-left function but not class dropdown-menu-right?

How to use a font family for the whole navbar, including the dropdown menu and text alight on the right side, with everything dropping from right to left. Actually, I'm working on an Urdu website (local language on the left side).
http://jsfiddle.net/saeedwifaq/gaLahmvz/

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle for your code?

Comment: ok, let me try it, first time i am creating on jsfiddle. :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/saeedwifaq/gaLahmvz/ check it Ajai

Comment: how apply font-family for whole navbar, including dropdown menu and text alight on right side, everything drop from right to left. Actually i am making urdu website, (local language right to left side)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***pull-right***

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
```

Easy and cool~

Class "dropdown-menu-right" is not working in Bootstrap v3.0.*